# Autodesk forge : home and information icons disappeared

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a 3D viewer on my web page, it's ok.
I have added a second 2D viewer (another div in my HTML) in order to display 2D sheets contained in the same model. It's ok.

Since I added this second viewer, the icon "home" and "information" have disappeared from the 3D viewer. I have only the view cube in my 3D viewer and "home" and "information" in my 2D viewer.

How can I make "come back" these 2 icons in my 3D viewer ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the Element source of your site, since I believe your Div might be going out of sight and it might be in a non visible section of your div containing the 3D viewer. 
Check that first. You can see this by seeing the Developer Tools in your browser and checking the Div html tag.